# Scrapy 1.0+ proper settings access in CsvItemExporter subclass?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Previously, accessing settings in a subclass of `CsvItemExporter`, which I need to modify the delimiter specified in the settings, could be done using:

```
from scrapy.conf import settings
```

However that method is now depreciated:

> ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.conf` is deprecated, use `crawler.settings` attribute instead
>         from scrapy.conf import settings

How can I do it now? The usual `from_crawler`, "`from_settings` class methods don't work in `CsvItemExporter`.

Comment: from what I can see there are no way to set CSV exporter delimiter using  settings, simplest is to create your own class, set CsvItemExporter as your base class and in __init__ call super wit additional parameters

Comment: I think this is something worth bringing up in the Scrapy issue tracker.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to extend feed exporters with additional parameters. In fact, a feature request exists asking for it:  [[Enhancement] Allow BaseItemExporter to accept arguments #973](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/973)

There are also 2 feature requests about allowing to customize the CSV delimiter:

- [CsvItemExporter delimiter should be changeable through settings.py #3252](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/3252)
- [Adding delimiter, quotechar, encoding, lineterminator options to the CSV exporter #3486](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/3486)

So, I suggest you track those requests, consider voting for them (i.e. adding a thumbs up reaction) or providing feedback otherwise, and in the meantime you can either ignore the warning, supress it, or go with [nyov’s approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54147540/939364).

Answer (score 1):

If there is no other way to access settings, you can try to replace

```
from scrapy.conf import settings
```

with

```
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
settings = get_project_settings()
```

which is essentially what the current compatibility shim in `scrapy/conf.py` does.
(It still exists at this point, 3 years later :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that everything is setup correctly, the unfamiliar with that error Trace,  whenever I do  use CSVitemexporter, I do it by creating an additional module with them project to be the CSVitemexporter and then just simply State my The deliminator like this...

yournameformodule.py

```
from scrapy.conf import settings
from scrapy.contrib.exporter import CsvItemExporter

class MyProjectCsvItemExporter(CsvItemExporter):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        delimiter = settings.get('CSV_DELIMITER', ',')
        kwargs['delimiter'] = delimiter

        fields_to_export = settings.get('FIELDS_TO_EXPORT', [])
        if fields_to_export :
            kwargs['fields_to_export'] = fields_to_export

        super(MyProjectCsvItemExporter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

then making sure that in your settings you list the items (also in your items.py)

settings.py

```
FEED_EXPORTERS = {
    'csv': 'PROJECTNAME.YOURNAMEFORMODULE.MyProjectCsvItemExporter',
}
FIELDS_TO_EXPORT = [
    'etc',
    'etc2',]
```

The one thing I am sure of the process works the same or a spider as if there's a crawl spider, though I can't see why not, I have not tested other than using a crawler for now. If you're still stuck on this keys of life with your project files to better help you out.